# Render react component based on dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm struggling to render a component based on routes from the React-Router. When the route is dynamic I can't seem to figure out a way to match the route.

I have created a component "Navbar" which I want to render only on specific routes. For this purpose I created a separate component "Tracker" which matches the route and renders the "Navbar" component.

**Tracker.js snippet:**

```
class Tracker extends Component {
  render() {
var NavVisible =
      this.props.location.pathname === "/feed" ||
      this.props.location.pathname === "/explore" ||
      this.props.location.pathname === "/chatroom" ||
      this.props.location.pathname === "/username" ? (
        <Navbar />
      ) : null;
    return <div>{NavVisible}</div>;
  }
}
```

Suppose if I have to display the Navbar component in "**feed/(some_dynamic_path)**", how should I write the condition?

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component{


  render(){

  const DefaultContainer = () => (
    <div>

      <Route path='/home' component={ft}/>
        <Route path='/explore' component={exp}/>
        <Route path='/compose' component={add}/>
        <Route path='/chatroom' component={msg}/>
        <Route path='/user' component={usrpro}/>

        </div>
  )

return (
    <BrowserRouter>    
    <div className="App">
      <Tracker/>
      <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Splash}/>
      <Route exact path="/(compose)" component={noNavContainer}/>
      <Route exact path="/(newtext)" component={noNavContainer}/>
      <Route path="/(login)" component={login}/>
      <Route component={DefaultContainer}/>        
      </Switch>      
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
this.props.location.pathname === '/feed/' + this.props.params.id
```

Might get you started: https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/

Comment: The logic is fine, but since the Tracker component is rendered from App.js, the match props always has an url "/" however the isExact seems to work fine. Seems to be an issue [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5870) with react-router. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You can include Routers for various urls like this in your app.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Home>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/feed/:path_variable' component={Navbar} />
          </Switch>
        </Home>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Also In Navbar Component, You will get access to `this.props.match.params.path_variable`  whose value changes based on the URL.

Read more about it in this nicely written article.
https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comment to @brooksrelyt answer, there seems to be an issue with react-router. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you post your app.js file

Comment: Updated the question.